# How can I interpret openssl speed output?

Tags: openssl

I ran `openssl speed` on my Ubuntu computer. Some results:

```
Doing md4 for 3s on 16 size blocks: 9063888 md4's in 3.00s
Doing md4 for 3s on 64 size blocks: 7105157 md4's in 3.00s
Doing md4 for 3s on 256 size blocks: 4507884 md4's in 3.00s
Doing md4 for 3s on 1024 size blocks: 1809773 md4's in 2.99s
Doing md4 for 3s on 8192 size blocks: 275679 md4's in 3.00s
```

What exactly those numbers mean?

1. what is 'Doing md4 for 3s' mean?
    does it mean do the whole test for 3 times/seconds?
2. what does '1809773 md4's in 2.99s' mean?
3. what does '8192 size blocks' mean?

> ```
> The 'numbers' are in 1000s of bytes per second processed.
> type             16 bytes     64 bytes    256 bytes   1024 bytes   8192 bytes
> md4              47363.12k   151534.29k   382055.94k   615801.51k   747692.03k
> ```

And the above, last lines of `openssl speed md4` output - what does they mean exactly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While it could probably be worded better, it pretty much means what it says - run the `md4` hash routine in a loop for 3 seconds with a 16 byte input. After 3 seconds, observe that we ran just a bit over 9 million iterations. That's about 144 million bytes processed, or 48 million bytes per second (where "million" means 10^6).

Comment: thank you! Could you be so kind and explain to me also `openssl` output (the last lines of output for a command: `openssl speed md4`? Here are those last lines: `The 'numbers' are in 1000s of bytes per second processed.
type             16 bytes     64 bytes    256 bytes   1024 bytes   8192 bytes
md4              47363.12k   151534.29k   382055.94k   615801.51k   747692.03k
` I will add them also to my main question ;)

Comment: For most of the hash and cipher algorithms, the throughput (how many bytes per second can be hashed/encrypted) depends on the block size you use as input - in other words hashing data 8KB at a time (747MB/s in your example) is faster than hashing it 16 bytes at a time (which comes in at only 47MB/s). That's what `openssl speed` does, is run each algorithm for a while with different block sizes to show you the throughput you can expect if you use it a certain way...

Comment: @twalberg: so if I have an input buffer of length 1024 (`char buf[1024];`) and run for it MD5 from `openssl` its the same as blocks size in openssl speed?

Comment: If you process the entire buffer in one call, yes.

Comment: @twalberg: I run it like this: `MD5(buf, strlen(buf), digest);` so I guess its processing entire buffer in one call? cheers btw for help!:)

Comment: `strlen(buf)` will only count up to the first NULL byte in your buffer (assuming there is one - if there isn't you may be reading out of bounds), but if your intention is to hash a NULL-terminated string, that will handle the entire string in one pass...

Comment: Hi, what does 'openssl speed aes' mean, only encryption or both encryption and decryption? thanks